# Windows phone 8 ListBox becomes empty after loading a lot of data

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 application I have a listbox which performs Lazy load. All is working fine except one thing. Sometimes after scrolling up or down, even when data is the same, my listbox becomes empty. I analized the used memory using "Windows phone application analyses" and got the maximum used memory 100MB. So there is no problem with memory. Also aplication does not crash after becoming listbox empty. Do you have any ideas why these happen?

Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="lbCollections" LayoutUpdated="lbCollectins_LayoutUpdated">
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="White" Margin="20">
                        <Grid Margin="15,5,15,5">                                
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding  CategoryName}" Foreground="Black" Style="{StaticResource EmptyListHeaderStyle}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding CreatedOn, StringFormat='{}{0:MM dd, yyyy}'}" Foreground="Gray" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PhotosCountTxt}" Foreground="Gray" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Height="150">
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <conv:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" />
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="img1" Source="{Binding Photos, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Name="img2" Source="{Binding Photos, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"></Image>
                            <Image Grid.Column="2" Name="img3" Source="{Binding Photos, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="5"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
private async void LoadContent()
    {
        if (loadingProgress)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                loadingProgress = true;
                CollectionResponse collectionResp = await CollectionService.IterateAsync(MapPoint, "", dtStart, dtEnd, filterCategoryId, loadedCollectionsCount, collectionsCountToLoadAtOnce, 4, (int)TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes, AppSettings.Invisible, AppSettings.Token);
                if (collectionResp.Collections.Count == 0)
                {
                    endOfList = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    loadedCollectionsCount += collectionResp.Collections.Count;
                    if (!(lbCollections.ItemsSource is List<CollectionModel>))
                    {
                        lbCollections.ItemsSource = new List<CollectionModel>();
                    }
                    (lbCollections.ItemsSource as List<CollectionModel>).AddRange(collectionResp.Collections);
                    //lbCollections.ItemsSource = collectionResp.Collections;
                }                    
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                loadingProgress = false;
            }
        }

    }

    private void lbCollectins_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        ScrollBar scrollBar = FindChildOfType<ScrollBar>(lbCollections).Where(sb=>sb.Orientation == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical).FirstOrDefault();
        if (scrollBar != null)
        {
            bool endOfScroll = scrollBar.Maximum > 0 && scrollBar.Value > 0 && scrollBar.Maximum - scrollBar.Value < 10;
            if (!endOfList && endOfScroll)
            {
                LoadContent();
            }
        }            
    }

    static List<T> FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
    {
        List<T> foundObjects = new List<T>();
        var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
        queue.Enqueue(root);

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
            for (int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null)
                {
                    foundObjects.Add(typedChild);
                }
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
        return foundObjects;
    }
```

Comment: P.S. The ListBox becomes empty only during very fast scrolling.

Comment: try the LongListSelector from WP Toolkit( http://phone.codeplex.com/ ). It has better performance. Perhaps it will solve this issue..

Comment: I can obviously try LongListSelector, but the question is why this occurs. The data of the Listbox becomes empty without any exception or notification. Is this a bug of WP8 or it has some reasonable answer?

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Yes, sure. But got no additional useful information. One aditional thing, after listbox becoming empty I can continue to scroll the white empty screen.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do.

1. Take a look at [this blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/05/16/listbox-why-art-thou-blanking.aspx) about why the ListBox goes blank. Most likely the problem is the images you are showing. You can easily fix by doing the following
2. Start using the LongListSelector for WP8 (not the WP Toolkit version!) It is designed for fast scrolling even with images